# Difference between MemoryRouter and Router concerning testing with react-testing-library

Tags: react-router-dom, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I work on a small App to get familiar with testing and such in React, using jest and React-Testing-Library.

In my `<App />` Component, I have a `Routes` with two `Route`. One of those looks like this:

`<Route path='/' element={<RequireAuth><Dashboard /></RequireAuth>} />`

If the user is not logged in, `<RequireAuth />` redirects the user to a  `Login />` Component via `<Navigate to="/login" />`.

This is just for context. All of this works. But for quite some time, I couldnt make the test pass to check that the Navigation happens. I figured, that my problem was the Route method I used in React-Testing-Libraries`render()` method. The test passes if I use `<MemoryRouter />` but doesnt if I wrap `<App />` in `<Router location={history.location} navigator={history} />.`.

In the following stackblitz, I have implemented both versions. The one that s not working, is currently commented out. Could someone tell me, why it only works with MemoryRouter? You find the test in src/routing.test.tsx. You can run the tests with npm run test.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-nfj4lw?file=src/routes.test.tsx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Router` is a low level function that [is not environment specific](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#router). As the docs state, you probably never want to render your components with it.
Replacing it with higher level environment aware functions like `BrowserRouter` or (`MemoryRouter`) makes your test pass:

```js
// routes.test.tsx
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
it('Testing if Route Login gets rendered by default', () => {
  render(
    
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  expect(
    screen.getByText('Welcome to nutri. Please Login.')
  ).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

If you want something more, you can add further assertions by querying the location/history stack.

**Note**: using [MemoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#memoryrouter) in tests is preferred to `BrowserRouter` since it allows you to keep your routing history independent of any external source. React-router uses it [in many of its tests.](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/__tests__/Router-test.tsx)